# How to trigger css and js load with Android WebView loadData

Tags: android, webview, httpclient

How can I make a WebView request the CSS and javascript links when I load HTML externally into the WebView?
This question is similar to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608714/css-and-js-files-not-loading-in-android-webview
but we are loading everything from a server. In order to support SSL Pinning we override the

```
loadUrl(String url)
```

method (and will override the others) and handle the request with an HttpClient.execute call. When we receive the data back from the network, then we push it into the webview with

```
WebView.loadData(event.getContent(), event.getMimeType(), event.getEncoding());
```

How should we implement this design to retrieve data externally and then load it into the webview?  The approach above shows the HTML fine but the CSS files are not loaded.

Comment: Also tried by setting the base URL with: loadDataWithBaseURL(String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl)

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Use the loadDataWithBaseURL. Then the WebView will fire requests to load the css/js/png. The tricky part is you can override WebView.loadUrl for the initial request but then override WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest for each of the css/js/png requests. In there you can fire your network request and return the response as a stream (WebResourceResponse).